# Stored Value Sets that are accessed throughout a Bixby Voice Experience

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am completely new to Bixby development so I apologize in advance if this is a newby question that doesn't make sense.  I'm trying to understand the best way to store value sets returned from external APIs to use throughout Bixby Voice experiences.  An example might be an API that gets all the menu items at a restaurant or an API that gets all the clothing catalog items from a store.  When users interact with the data to search or transact I don't want to have to go back to the external API to get the value set again.  For example: Find Vegan Menu options followed by Okay how about pescatarian options.  Or: Find dress pants followed by okay how about dress shirts.  I'd like to come back to a menu object in the first case or a catalog object in the second without having to re-load the value sets from the API.

In the sample code I've seen all of the value sets appear to be read in each time an action/endpoint/java call is made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no local storage in the current version of Bixby.

The easiest solution is to request through API calls. However, http.getUrl() itself is cached by default, and Bixby runs on Samsung server, so no actual API calls in practice when requesting same url in short sessions.

You can read more about http API options and how to disable cache feature by reading more [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/http#http-options)

Comment: Thanks that is helpful.  For content that may change somewhat frequently I'll set cache time out options and for more static content I'll let the server side cache by default

Comment: What counts as the "same URL" for the purposes of caching? For example, suppose you are calling the AllMenus API to get what's on the menu at different restaurants. The API takes the restaurant name as a query string, e.g., "https://allmenus.com?restaurant=annies". Is this a different url than "https://allmenus.com?restaurant=bobs"? If not, then will we have to set the cacheTime to 0 and keep hitting the API as the user keeps asking questions about Annie's menu?

Comment: It has to be exact API call (including parameters). In your example, you don't need to set cacheTime to 0